# Computed column should result to string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, string, calculated-columns

Here is a snap of my database.

Both col1 and col2 are declared as int.

My ComputedColumn currently adds the Columns 1 and 2, as follows...

```
col1  col2  ComputedColumn
1     2     3
4     1     5
```

Instead of this, my ComputedColumn should join the columns 1 and 2 (includimg the **'-'** character in the middle) as follows...

```
col1  col2  ComputedColumn
1     2     1-2
4     1     4-1
```

So, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably defining your computed column as `col1+col2`.  Try `CAST(col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+'-'+CAST(col2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` instead.

Or if you prefer, you can replace `NVARCHAR(MAX)` with `NVARCHAR(10)` or a different length of your choice.

Comment: I think NVARCHAR(MAX) is overkill!, they are INTs, so there is a max length and can't contain any strange unicode characters!!! so varchar(11) would be fine.

Comment: @KM Good point, particularly on the `VARCHAR` vs. `NVARCHAR`.  The length is a lesser concern - as long as the total length of the row doesn't exceed the allowable row size (4K?), I believe there will be no practical difference between using MAX versus the 11 you suggest.

Comment: if this is a computed column that is not PERSISTED, you will potentially do this calculation millions of times, depending on how many SELECTs you do on this column.  I would think there is some overhead when doing string operations on (MAX) vs (n) columns.  Why take the chance, the int can't be larger than varchar(11).

Comment: @KM Yeah, you're probably right.  For short fields on a table (assuming the table's set to 'large text out of row = false'), there shouldn't be an appreciable difference in read and write time.  But I couldn't find documentation relating to processing overhead, or how MAX fields are treated in query results.  So I'd definitely go with your version - better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 4):

```
create table TableName
(
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    ComputedColumn as Convert(varchar, col1) + '-' + Convert(varchar, col2)
)
```

Bear in mind that if either value is `null` then the result of `ComputedColumn` will also be `null` (using the default collation and settings)

Answer (score 0):

simple:

```
SELECT ComputedColumn = convert(varchar, col1) + '-' + convert(varchar, col2)
  FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, col2, (col1 + '-' + col2) as ComputedColumn
```

"+" is both addition and the concatenation character. You could explicitly convert, but in this case, including the '-' in the middle should cause an implicit conversion.

Comment: i think it does not. It still adds the columns

Comment: Ah, thats funny, but I think I know why. SELECT 4+'a'+6 returns a syntax error "Syntax error converting the varchar value 'A' to a column of data type int", so it must be doing the implicit conversion the wrong way (its converting '-' to an integer (0), then adding them all together)

Answer (score 0):

first create table in design mode

add 2 column as col1 and col2

add another column computedcolumn and set computed column property

[image]

Also you can use that following script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl](
[col1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[col2] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ComputedColumn]  AS ((CONVERT([varchar],[col1],(0))+'-')+CONVERT([varchar],[col2],(0)))
```

)