# SQL computed column evaluating numbers should return string

Tags: sql, calculated-columns, sql-server-2016

A similar question is here: [Computed column should result to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472760/computed-column-should-result-to-string#)

However in my case, I cannot cast the numeric values to strings. I need to evaluate the numbers and based on them return a text description. Is that possible?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.test ADD classTest AS CASE 
    WHEN speed > 10 THEN 'fast'
    ELSE 'error' END
```

Otherwise I suppose I can return numbers that correspond to text values in a look-up table and create a view...

---

Unfortunately I edited out my syntax error yesterday, I think I was missing the 'END' and an apostrophe somewhere. The fix didn't seem to work yesterday but I just tried it again and things are moving smoothly.

Comment: you have syntax errors in `case`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. Just a couple of syntax errors.  Single quotes and END

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.test ADD classTest AS CASE 
    WHEN speed > 10 THEN 'fast'
    ELSE 'error' END

Select * from test


speed   classTest
11      fast
5       error
```