# MySQL Query to add value in multiple rows corresponding to the id column

Tags: mysql

MySQL Query to add value in multiple rows of the single table corresponding to the id column. I want to add data to all the rows like

```
column_id->1  column_req->abc-10001
column_id->2  column_req->abc-10002
column_id->3  column_req->abc-10003
column_id->4  column_req->abc-10004
```

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: If the prefix is always abc- then why bother?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472760/computed-column-should-result-to-string. You can create a computed column where you get this value

Comment: Can you explain what exactly needs to be added where by which rule? Do you want to persist the added data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_req = CONCAT('abc-', (10000 + column_id))
```

But you shouldn't store values like this. If this rule is fixed and doesn't change in future you can use a `SELECT` on your application instead:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT('abc-', (10000 + column_id)) AS column_req FROM table_name
```

---

You can also [create a view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) to solve this:

```
CREATE VIEW custom_table_name AS
    SELECT *, CONCAT('abc-', (10000 + column_id)) AS column_req FROM table_name
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26cffe631226c95d8e66db186b5e4320)

Comment: i am using this :-UPDATE abc_productmanagement_request SET request_no = CONCAT('AFP-', (10000 + id)) AS request_no FROM abc_productmanagement_request;

Comment: but showing error  "you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS request_no FROM diaspark_productmanagement_request' at line 1"

Comment: try the following: `UPDATE diaspark_productmanagement_request SET request_no = CONCAT('AFP-', (10000 + id))`