# How to create a URL in a SQL table that is the product of different data in the same row

Tags: sql, database, url

I am trying to create a cell based URL for each row in a table based on the data from other columns in the same table in the same row.
For example let's say we have a table like the illustration below:

[image]

Is this possible to do ?

Best regards,
Oscar

Comment: You shouldn't store data computed from other columns. If someone updates the product name only, your URL will have the old product name - i.e. data inconsistency. Either create a view, or have a _computed column_, or at least use triggers.

Comment: Great point Jarlh. Do you have any examples to illustrate your solution ? How would a trigger or a computed column be built in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017):

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME ADD url AS ('www.shoes.com/' + id + '/' + country + '/' + product) PERSISTED

//PERSISTED stores the column result physically in the database
```

Note: if there are different data type in columns you should [convert them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472760/computed-column-should-result-to-string) before concatenating.

Alternatively you can create an alias column on the fly when selecting data instead of creating a computed column:

```
select ('www.shoes.com/' + id + '/' + country + '/' + product) as MYURL from MYTABLE
```

Comment: Thank you Ali, exactly was I was looking for.